# Save List To PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, save, pymongo, database

Never used PyMongo so I'm new to this stuff. I want to be able to save one of my lists to MongoDB. For example, I have a list `imageIds = ["zw8SeIUW", "f28BYZ"]`, which is appended to frequently. After each `append`, the list `imageIds` should be saved to the database.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = client.databaseForImages
```

and then later

```
imageIds.append(data)
db.databaseForImages.save(imageIds)
```

Why doesn't this work? What is the solution?

Comment: Have you gone through the [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)?  You need to store your data as a Python dict, not a list.

Comment: Yep. Just a little confused. Will you give me some source code to do that?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Also isn't what I have a dict? I always get confused.

Comment: No, that's an array/list.  A dict would look like `{"ids": imageIds}`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ok so can I have some help?

Comment: I'm guessing you want someone to write code for you? That won't happen here unless you give more details about what you're doing, what are the use cases, requirements, etc.

Comment: @notorious No...I'd like someone to help me as I'm learning PyMongo. I want to be able to update a list, and then retrieve it when the server restarts.

Answer (score 5):

First, if you don't know what a python dict is, I recommend brushing up on Python fundamentals . Check out Google's Python Class or Learn Python the Hard Way. Otherwise, you will be back here every 10 minutes with a new question...

Now, you have to connect to the mongoDB server/instance:

```
client = MongoClient('hostname', port_number)
```

Connect to a database:

```
db = client.imagedb
```

Then save the record to the collection "image_data".

```
record = {'image_ids': imageIds}
db.image_data.save(record)
```

Using save(), the record dict is updated with an '_id' field which now points to the record in this collection. To update it with a new appended imageIds:

```
record['image_ids'] = imageIds # Already contains the original _id
db.image_data.save(record)
```

Comment: Everything works fine, but when I restart the server the newly added object to the dict has disappeared.

Comment: That's a different question! First: _you need to go through the pymongo tutorial_. If you don't understand how the system works, you won't get anywhere...

Comment: Please, do what Sp00n3r says, it will be the best.